# Android Tablelayout show all dividers

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, divider

Is it possible for an Android Tablelayout to display all dividers (see picture below) using the xml attributes?

I've spend a bit of time searching the internet and find that a lot of people just use customised views.

Is there any way to do this in xml or another better method?

example(don't mind the varying border thickness):
[image]

Comment: I can't understand your question .Do you want set border to the table layout ?

Comment: So you want to show the dividers on a tablelayout?

Comment: You want to show grid line???

Comment: @RakeshL No, I simply want to show dividers between every row & column and at the sides.

Comment: @ZeeshanKhan pretty much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this by using the following code

Create a selector xml in drawable folder with below code

**valuecellborder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<!--     <solid android:color="#dc6888"/>     -->
    <stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Now in your layout xml code in TableRow tag put

```
android:background="@drawable/valuecellbroder"
```

in every item tag such as Textview background

Comment: When the size of the inner View (i.e. each view item inside the TableRow) varies in case the height is not fixed(wrap_content) then their borders may show differently(zigzag) not in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used this method.
I set Table background to black, then set table row background white with TopMargin.
In .xml :

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

In .java :

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
tr.setBackgroundColor(resource.getColor(R.color.white));
int topMargin = 2;  // border Thickness
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams =
        new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 250);  // 250 is my row height
tableRowParams.setMargins(0, topMargin, 0, 0);
tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, off the top of my head, to give you the lines you seek is to have each cell of the TableLayout or GridLayout be some container containing the widget(s) for that cell, where you give the container a background that is your line. A ShapeDrawable could be defined in XML for that background, which will be nicely resizeable based upon the actual requirements of the cell.